# Open Source/Free software for locking folders

Tags: windows, open-source, password-manager

I am looking for a free software that can lock folders on my Windows system. I have tried many softwares like file locker, folder locker but they are only available in trial versions.

I have a folder which is shared between a mobile device and comp. Right now I am using axcrypt to encrypt the files. This makes them unreadable by mobile device. I want a free software that will password protect the folder but do not encrypt the files inside.

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but is it technically possible to lock a folder, without encryption? If you transfer the folder to another system which does not care about the password, then the folder can still be opened. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I doubt you will find the ability to lock folders without encrypting there contents as this would be a poor design choice.

Comment: A possible solution can be encrypted folder. It actually depends how you share between PC and mobile. Could you be more specific in your question. Do yo use cloud storage to share?

Comment: yes, i use google drive to share.

Comment: I haven't used this software before but it looks promising: [Password Folder](http://password-folder.en.softonic.com/). It seems to be free and it doesn't mention encryption, even though it could encrypt. One note: how will Google Drive access the files when they are locked? You need a service that locks the files *and* syncs them so you don't have permissions problems.

Answer (score 2):

[Wise Folder Hider](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wisefolderhider.html) is a free folder and file hider. It is password protected and we can set other password to hidden files and folders(double password protected). Once a folder or file is hidden by this software, it can't be seen anywhere else. This software is also light weight(less than 3 MB). I have been using it for more than 2 years and never thought of using another app.

Answer (score 0):

a) Use truecrypt to create a container (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt). It is discontinued, but still open-source and free and is a trusted encryption s/w.

b) Mount the container as a Volume/Drive with the password and create a folder inside it

c) Use this folder as the shared folder between mobile and system. Unmount the volume when not in use.